# Remove unused emails from Woocommerce settings emails list

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, email-notifications

A few days ago I've asked how I can rename custom email templates in WooCommerce. Now I have the problem that I have some email templates which I don't need and I want to hide these templates completely. How can I do this? I've searched on SO and Google but can't find a tutorial.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** The right solution is using [`woocommerce_email_classes`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Emails.html#206) filter hook locate in `WC_Emails` Class:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_classes', 'remove_specific_email_classes', 10, 1 );
function remove_specific_email_classes( $emails ) {
    unset($emails['WC_Email_New_Order']);
    unset($emails['WC_Email_Cancelled_Order']);
    unset($emails['WC_Email_Failed_Order']);
    unset($emails['WC_Email_Customer_On_Hold_Order']);
    unset($emails['WC_Email_Customer_Processing_Order']);
    unset($emails['WC_Email_Customer_Completed_Order']);
    unset($emails['WC_Email_Customer_Refunded_Order']);
    unset($emails['WC_Email_Customer_Invoice']);
    unset($emails['WC_Email_Customer_Note']);
    unset($emails['WC_Email_Customer_Reset_Password']);
    unset($emails['WC_Email_Customer_New_Account']);

    return $emails;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (active theme). Tested and works.

---

The following [official Woocommerce documented](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/unhookremove-woocommerce-emails/) hooked function will remove notifications action hooks:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email', 'unhook_those_pesky_emails' );
function unhook_those_pesky_emails( $email_class ) {

    //Hooks for sending emails during store events
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_low_stock_notification', array( $email_class, 'low_stock' ) );
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_no_stock_notification', array( $email_class, 'no_stock' ) );
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_product_on_backorder_notification', array( $email_class, 'backorder' ) );

    // New order emails
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_processing_notification', array( $email_class->emails['WC_Email_New_Order'], 'trigger' ) );
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_completed_notification', array( $email_class->emails['WC_Email_New_Order'], 'trigger' ) );
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_on-hold_notification', array( $email_class->emails['WC_Email_New_Order'], 'trigger' ) );
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_failed_to_processing_notification', array( $email_class->emails['WC_Email_New_Order'], 'trigger' ) );
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_failed_to_completed_notification', array( $email_class->emails['WC_Email_New_Order'], 'trigger' ) );
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_failed_to_on-hold_notification', array( $email_class->emails['WC_Email_New_Order'], 'trigger' ) );

    // Processing order emails
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_processing_notification', array( $email_class->emails['WC_Email_Customer_Processing_Order'], 'trigger' ) );
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_on-hold_notification', array( $email_class->emails['WC_Email_Customer_Processing_Order'], 'trigger' ) );

    // Completed order emails
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed_notification', array( $email_class->emails['WC_Email_Customer_Completed_Order'], 'trigger' ) );

    // Note emails
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_new_customer_note_notification', array( $email_class->emails['WC_Email_Customer_Note'], 'trigger' ) );
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: I've added a solution too. Which solution will be the better one?

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution. I'm not sure whats better?

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_classes', 'remove_unused_emails', 15 );
function remove_unused_emails( $email_classes ) {

    //Unset unused email templates
    unset( $email_classes['WC_Email_Customer_Reset_Password'] );
    unset( $email_classes['WC_Email_Customer_New_Account'] );
    unset( $email_classes['WC_Email_Customer_On_Hold_Order'] );
    unset( $email_classes['WC_GZD_Email_Customer_New_Account_Activation'] );
    unset( $email_classes['WC_GZD_Email_Customer_Revocation'] );
    unset( $email_classes['WC_GZD_Email_Customer_Ekomi'] );
    unset( $email_classes['WC_GZD_Email_Customer_Trusted_Shops'] );

    return $email_classes;

}
```

Comment: Yes I just find this also… It is the solution, to remove emails…